Using OdbcBulkCopy via Pythonnet gives ModuleNotFoundError
I have the following code which attempts to load OdbcBulkCopy using pythonnet:
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/workspace_py/odbcbulkcopy.2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/")
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
clr.AddReference('OdbcBulkCopy')

from System.Data import Odbc
from OdbcBulkCopy import OdbcBulkCopy

But it fails on the last line with the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OdbcBulkCopy'
I downloaded OdbcBulkCopy from the nuget site, unlocked and unzipped, the OdbcBulkCopy.dll is contained in the "C:/workspace_py/odbcbulkcopy.2.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/" which I am appending to the path in the above code.
Does anyone know how to get this working?
Source of OdbcBulkCopy library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OdbcBulkCopy
I've tried adding the dll directly into the path, but that just gives a file not found exception on the clr.AddReference('OdbcBulkCopy')
